# How to change shell prompt in Unix?

Tags: shell, character

I want to disable the Unix shell prompt character (`$`, `#`, `%`) which usually we see in terminal. Is there any command or setting which can do this? I am using Solaris OS.

By shell prompt character I mean:

```
>$
>#
```

Comment: What shell are you using? (`echo $SHELL`) That's your shell prompt; why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Neither `>$` nor `>#` is a standard prompt; the `>` is not part of the standard prompts.  The `#` traditionally indicates 'root user', and is meant to be a warning that you're dangerously powerful, whereas `$` (in the Bourne shell family – `%` in the C shell family) indicates an ordinary mortal user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your PS1 environment variable in your .profile file.
I guess you could set it to "" to have it empty.

ex:
`export PS1=""`

EDIT: it can also be in your .bashrc file, or any other shell you are using.

Comment: +1: And then there's the continuation prompt, `PS2="> "` by default; maybe the OP doesn't want that either, though it's tricky to spot why the computer's not doing anything if the empty continuation prompt is showing.  Personally, I always set the prompt, but to something short like `PS1="Osiris JL: "` on a machine `osiris`, and the `PS2` prompt aligns the `>` with the `:`.  I dislike the prompts that include, for example, the current directory; it has something to do with working in directories with a pathname that is 80-120 characters long; even on a 120-column terminal, it looks silly!

Answer (score 1):

You can get fancy and put the host name in there.  But basically you change the PS1 environment variable:

```
export PS1=hello
```

You can add this command in your ~/.bashrc file.  Or other startup file, if you use another shell.

Comment: +1: Note that `PS1` isn't an environment variable by default.  I use that property and don't make it into an environment variable so I can tell when I'm in a sub-shell.  (That also means I don't set it in my `~/.bashrc` file; I set it in my `.profile`, once, when the login shell starts.)  Each to their own, of course; other people may not like that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first check the man pages for the shell (whatever is yours? echo $SHELL) under shell variables. 
There are four types of prompt strings(PS) PS1, PS2, PS3, PS4, for your problem PS1 adjustment is sufficient.
To check the current settings:     `echo $PS1`

To change: `PS1=""` for the current session, to make it permanent export it in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile.

To make it permanent for the user: export `PS1="whatever special characters you want"`

for more special characters and examples you can visit here "http://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics"

Comment: Thank you all for you help..!!