# Turn off terminal entry line prefix/header

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image]

How do I fix this? I don't want to change my server name I just want to customize the text here (no server name, still shows path/user). Also what's this section of the terminal window called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change shell prompt in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410215/how-to-change-shell-prompt-in-unix) (sorry, could not find a better dupe).

Comment: Depending on your shell, but you have environment variables to control the shell prompt : `PS1`, `PS2, `prompt`, etc. Read the manual of the shell you use.

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer here, maybe one day this will help users who don't know the search term "shell prompt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terminal Entry line prefix is called the shell prompt.

You can generally find the current config by typing

```
echo $PS1
```

That returned this for me: [\e]0;\u@^C\w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

So I was able to remove the "@\h" in both locations and get the desired tag.

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\w\$ "
```

leaving me with "root:/kliq$'